# how to make excluded variables dynamic in ansible

Tags: ansible

i am trying to make a playbook to change permissions across all servers, but i need to exclude few directories and files. I am trying to make the files allocation dynamic , as you can see i have excluded 2 , but i want to make it generalized or dynamic . plz suggest .

Below is my playbook, please note i am using directory structure :

```
permission.yml: 
---
- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  roles:
    - { role: fileperm, target_dir: "/tmp/testingpermissions" }
    - { role: fileperm, target_dir: "/tmp/abc" }
    - { role: fileperm, target_dir: "/amp/app/tomcatdefault7055" }


Vars:
main.yml:
  ---
  exclude1: "/tmp/testingpermissions/plugins"
  exclude2: "/tmp/testingpermissions/files"


tasks:
main.yml:
---
- name: Ensure directories are 0755
  command: find {{ target_dir }} -type d ! -path "{{ exclude1 }}*" ! -path "{{ exclude2 }}*" -exec chmod -c 0755 {} \;
  register: chmod_result
  changed_when: "chmod_result.stdout != \"\""
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You should consider reading the [ask] guide before asking a question. For more information about the site, you can visit the [tour] page.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the 'file' module, and loop through your list of directories that need to have their permissions changed,
e.g. sth like this in the vars:

```
# /vars/main.yml
updatepermissions:
  - "/tmp/testingpermissions"
  - "/tmp/abc"
  - "/amp/app/tomcatdefault7055"
```

... and then sth like this in the tasks:

```
# /tasks/main.yml
- name: Set directory permissions to 0755
  file:
    path: "{{ item }}"
    state: directory
    mode: 0755
  with_items: "{{ updatepermissions }}"
```

This will set the permissions on only the directories that you specify. So instead updating permissions for everything except for some excluded few, you'd only update the permissions on a set list of directories that need the given permissions.

For directories where you don't want to exclude any subdirectories from setting permissions, you can add "recurse=yes".

Otherwise, if you prefer the command task with "! -path", you could maybe do something like this:

```
# /vars/main.yml
updatepermissions:
  - include: "/tmp/testingpermissions"
    exclude: "! -path \"/tmp/testingpermissions/plugins\" ! -path \"/tmp/testingpermissions/abc\""
  - include: "/some/other/directory"
    exclude: ""
```

and then in the tasks sth like this:

```
# /tasks/main.yml
- name: update permissions
  command: "find {{ item.include }} -type d {{ item.exclude }} -exec chmod -c 0755 {} \;"
  register: chmod_result
  changed_when: "chmod_result.stdout != \"\""
  with_items: "{{ updatepermissions }}"
```

Comment: Thanks , this helps ,but my requirement is i have 30 40 different paths , which are NAS mounts i want to mark out . so it does not seem good to hardcode all paths . can i read it from a file and then use it ?                          For example i have 20 servers , i want go to each of them , run a command to take out all the NAS mounts on it and then mark them out of chmod . any ideas plz .